# Can I choose what blog posts will be displayed in the front page with Blogger?

Tags: blogger

I have a Blogger blog using the "simple" template. New posts are displayed in the front page.

Is it possible to select what posts will be displayed, rather than having all of them featured?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily:  In general if you have any posts on your "home page", then you will have all of them.

But depending on what you want to achieve - and how much work-around you are happy to do- there are some things you could try.

One option is to put the content that you don't want featured on your front screen into Pages instead of Posts.   Pages aren't part of your blog's "feed" or "stream" so don't show up in the list of posts:  you need to use a Pages gadget (or something) to let people get to them.  There is a limit of only 20 pages in total, and the expectation is that if the information changes, you edit the Page, rather than make a new one.

Another option is to use a custom-redirect so that your "home page" is never shown as the front screen.   Instead you can point to any other Page or Post (let's call it your pseudo home screen) and if you want some of your posts to be listed on the "front screen" you would have to edit this pseudo-home-screen to link to them.    (I've described this and a few other options in a bit more detail [here](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/setting-what-goes-on-home-page.html).)

Be aware that if you do this, and have enabled a mobile template for your blog, then mobile visitors will not get access, instead they will see a message about re-direct loops.   This is due to a bug in Blogger.

Comment: Apologies, now fixed.